# C++: Function Template to Handle Ints and Strings

Tags: c++, string, function-templates

I'm working on a programming assignment, to make a function template that can handle ints and doubles. I've done that, but for fun, I wanted to make it able to handle strings, as well. Here is the function below. How would I go about making it handle strings?

```
// This program demonstrates the QuickSort Algorithm.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h> //needed for string handling?
using namespace std;



//**********************************************************
// partition selects the value in the middle of the        *
// array set as the pivot. The list is rearranged so       *
// all the values less than the pivot are on its left      *
// and all the values greater than pivot are on its right. *
//**********************************************************

template <class T>
int partition(T set[], int start, int end)
{
   int pivotValue, pivotIndex, mid;

   mid = (start + end) / 2;
   swap(set[start], set[mid]);
   pivotIndex = start;
   pivotValue = set[start]; // main.cpp:28: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to 'int' in assignment
   for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
   {
      if (set[scan] < pivotValue) // main.cpp:31: error: no match for 'operator<' in '*(((std::string*)(((long unsigned int)scan) * 8ul)) + set) < pivotValue'
      {
         pivotIndex++;
         swap(set[pivotIndex], set[scan]);
      }
   }
   swap(set[start], set[pivotIndex]);
   return pivotIndex;
}

//************************************************
// quickSort uses the quicksort algorithm to     *
// sort set, from set[start] through set[end].   *
//************************************************

template <class T>
void quickSort(T set[], int start, int end)
{
   T pivotPoint;

   if (start < end)
   {
      // Get the pivot point.
      pivotPoint = partition(set, start, end);
      // Sort the first sub list.
      quickSort(set, start, pivotPoint - 1); // main.cpp:56: error: no match for 'operator-' in 'pivotPoint - 1'
      // Sort the second sub list.
      quickSort(set, pivotPoint + 1, end); // main.cpp:58: error: no match for 'operator+' in 'pivotPoint + 1'
   }
}

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 10;  // Array size
   int count;            // Loop counter

   // create arrays of various data types
   int array[SIZE] = {7, 3, 9, 2, 0, 1, 8, 4, 6, 5};
//   string array[SIZE] = {"7", "3", "9", "2","7", "3", "9", "2","a","r"};
   double array2[SIZE] = {7.1, 3.3, 9.0, 2.7, 0.2, 1.5, 8.9, 4.5, 6.9, 5.45};

   // Display the int array contents.
   cout << "Displaying the int array before sorting" << endl;
   for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
      cout << array[count] << " ";
   cout << endl;

   // Sort the int array.
   quickSort(array, 0, SIZE - 1);

   // Display the int array contents.
   cout << "Displaying the int array after sorting" << endl;
   for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
      cout << array[count] << " ";
   cout << endl << endl;

   // Display the double array contents.
   cout << "Diplaying the double array before sorting" << endl;
   for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
      cout << array2[count] << " ";
   cout << endl;

   // Sort the double array.
   quickSort(array2, 0, SIZE - 1);

   // Display the int array contents.
   cout << "Displaying the double array after sorting" << endl;
   for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
      cout << array2[count] << " ";
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: pivotValue should have type T, but not int. This code may work not as you expect for T=double because you assign a value of type T to int variable in line 28

Comment: Also, the type of pivotPoint probably should be int. It seems that after fixing this everything should work.

Comment: Got it @user502144! That's where the error was. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `std::string` for `T`, you're probably pretty close to working already.

If you use `char*`, you'll need to supply a comparison functor as a template parameter (or have some other way of specifying the comparison method for `T`, like a type-trait class).

Also, you shouldn't implement your own `swap`. `std::swap` already exists and will do smart things for certain types (e.g. swapping two `vector`s is constant-time instead of copying every object in the vector).

Comment: NOTE: if this is a homework assignment, you may be prohibited from using `std::swap`, in which case don't worry about it. :)

Comment: But then it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Thanks @StilesCrisis! I thought I was pretty close, too. I'm not going to worry about `char` for now. With `std::string` I thought I could use the existing relational operators. I've edited the question to add in the errors I'm encountering. Do those errors make sense to you? I've also removed the swap function.

Comment: You've mixed up your pivot values and pivot indexes (in the partition function, at least). Pivot values should be type `T`, and indexes `int`. Whatever compiler you're using should give a warning about conversion from double to int and possible loss of data - if not, try and enable this as it greatly helps in picking up possible bugs!

Answer (score 1):

Works in MSVC, which is a bit permissive so let me know if you run into problems with your compiler.

This solution uses functors (a class/struct with `operator()`) which means the object can be called as if it were a function. It also uses template specialization - take a look at what happens if you remove the `template < >` versions of `LessThanCompare` - `char*` will fall back to comparing the pointer value (giving random results).

In a better implementation you would use a class to put your quicksort and pivot functions - then you could use default templates and avoid having to call like `quickSort<char*, LessThanCompare<char*> >` - you could just say `quicksort` but that's getting a bit beyond the scope of the question!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct LessThanCompare
{
    bool operator()(T lhs, T rhs)
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};


template < >
struct LessThanCompare<char*>
{
    bool operator()(char* lhs, char* rhs)
    {
        return strcmp(lhs, rhs) == -1;  // Note strcmp returns -1 if lhs < rhs
    }
};

template <class T, class Comparator>
int partition(T set[], int start, int end)
{
    Comparator CompareLessThan; // Declare an instance of the Comparator

   T pivotValue; 
   int pivotIndex, mid;  // Is mid an index or a value - use descriptive names!

   mid = (start + end) / 2;
   swap(set[start], set[mid]);
   pivotIndex = start;
   pivotValue = set[start]; 
   for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
   {
      if (CompareLessThan(set[scan], pivotValue)) 
      {
         pivotIndex++;
         swap(set[pivotIndex], set[scan]);
      }
   }
   swap(set[start], set[pivotIndex]);
   return pivotIndex;
}

//************************************************
// quickSort uses the quicksort algorithm to     *
// sort set, from set[start] through set[end].   *
//************************************************

template <class T, class Comparator>
void quickSort(T set[], int start, int end)
{
   int pivotPoint;

   if (start < end)
   {
      // Get the pivot point.
      pivotPoint = partition<T, Comparator >(set, start, end);
      // Sort the first sub list.
      quickSort<T, Comparator>(set, start, pivotPoint - 1); // main.cpp:56: error: no match for 'operator-' in 'pivotPoint - 1'
      // Sort the second sub list.
      quickSort<T, Comparator>(set, pivotPoint + 1, end); // main.cpp:58: error: no match for 'operator+' in 'pivotPoint + 1'
   }
}

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 10;  // Array size

   // Create arrays of strings
   char* cstrArr[SIZE] = {
       "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};

   std::string strArr[SIZE];
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
   {
       strArr[i] = std::string(cstrArr[i]);
   }

   quickSort<char*, LessThanCompare<char*> >(cstrArr, 0, SIZE-1);
   quickSort<std::string, LessThanCompare<std::string> >(strArr, 0, SIZE-1);

   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
   {
       cout << cstrArr[i] << "\t\t" << strArr[i] << '\n';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, regarding style, use `<cstring>` instead of `<cstring.h>` (the former imports functions into namespace `std` while the latter pollutes the global namespace and might be needed for backwards compatibility). Personally I would not declare `int count` as a loop index in your main function - declare variables in the smallest scope possible. Any compiler worth using will optimize away the extra `int`.

Comment: This is pretty close to generic. Now just get rid of the array argument and it is good.

Comment: Yeah - but I didn't want to move too far from the homework solution. I think generic iterators might be a step too far!